# Unity animation not playing when made to in script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I want it so it plays an animation when you butter a piece of toast.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject ButterIt;
    private float myTimer = 0f;
    private bool isCounting = false;
    private Animation anim;
    public GameObject yellow;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        yellow.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward * 100);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform.tag == "Death")
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(true);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Stop Touching My Junk You Pervert! - Tickle Me Bender");
                    isCounting = true;
                }
            
            }
            else
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        if (isCounting)
        {
            myTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (myTimer > 2.5f)
        {
            yellow.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("WEE WOO WEE WOO - Patrick");
            isCounting = false;
            anim.Play("YellowFade");
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to make the screen turn yellow for a little bit of time then go into another scene. I tried looking all over the internet for help but I couldn't find anything or I was too stupid to apply it to my code.

This is what my animator looks like:

[Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XATMO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XATMO.png)

There is also an error saying: The AnimationClip "YellowFade" used by the animation component "anim" must be marked as legacy.

Then after I set it as legacy and trigger the animation it says: There is no animation attached to the Main Camera gameobject but a script it trying to access it you probably need to add an animation to to the game object MainCamera or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Then when I try to add the animation in it says legacy clips are not allowed in animation controllers.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this script attached to your main camera or another game object ?

Comment: @DevAm00 My main camera

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect type for the anim declaration. The correct one is Animator, that should solve all your problems

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Animation** component, for new projects use the animator component

- Add the animator component  instead of the animation component
- Make a new animator controller  and asign it to your animator component
- You have to delete the old animations and recreate them  or just change the animation type
- add them into the animator window and make sure the new animation name is YellowFade

Make these changes to your code

> ```
> private Animator anim; 
>
>
>
> anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
> ```